# How to import top level files in python using __init__

Tags: python

I want to import `main_file.py` from `sub_file.py`, i have my `init` files setup. I am able to do in my `main_file.py`:

```
from sub_folder.sub_file import *
```

However i do not know how to do it the other way around.

This is my structure:

```
|+main_folder
|--_init_.py
|--main_file.py
|++sub_folder
|---_init_.py
|---sub_file.py
```

Comment: Use underscore (`_`) instead of `-` then `import main_folder.main_file`

Comment: You might be interested in this [The Anatomy of a Python Project](http://infinitemonkeycorps.net/docs/pph/).  It's possible to do a [editable install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs) of your code to make it available like a package.

Comment: its just sudo code but i tried it but it does not seem to work

Comment: @e_man106, how are you running your script?

Comment: @e_man106, is `sub_folder` insdie `main_folder`?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf yes subfolder is in main folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old way:

- Make sure the directory with `main_folder` is on your `sys.path`;
- `from main_folder import main_file`.

The [new, usually better way](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html):

- `from ..main_folder import main_file`

This has the advantage of never clashing with system imports. If you rename your `main_folder` to e.g. `math`, `from math import my_func` will crash, because stdlib's `math` does not have this function, *or* import from  your module, depending on `sys.path`. OTOH `from ..math import my_func` will definitely always import from your own module.

If in doubt, always `print sys.path` before your failing import statement to understand if you're actually looking at the right directories.